# appending relative href link to the current url without javascript

Tags: html

seems like a very trivial problem but I am unable to figure it out.

I am on page http://example.com/emails

and I would like to add a hyperlink as

```
<a href="inbox">inbox</a>
```

this results in a http://example.com/inbox

but I would like it to go to http://example.com/emails/inbox

Obviously I can do that by writing full href link

```
<a href="emails/inbox">inbox</a>
```

Other method is using javascript to get the current window url and append href with that.

but I am wondering if there is already a way to handle this simply in html without using javascript just by using some relative url scheme.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use JS for taking the full URL/current page URL then you can use PHP. You can use PHP `$_SERVER` Superglobal built-in variable to get the current page URL. Here I am sharing 2-references for your better understanding, please go through this link hopefully it will help you.
[Get the full URL in PHP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-the-full-url-in-php/) & [Get current page URL in PHP](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-php.php)